# How do I read one number at a time and store it in an array, skipping duplicates?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read numbers from a file into an array, discarding duplicates. For instance, say the following numbers are in a file:

```
41 254 14 145 244 220 254 34 135 14 34 25
```

Though the number 34 occurs twice in the file, I would only like to store it once in the array. How would I do this?

(fixed, but I guess a better term would be a 64 bit Unsigned int) (was using numbers above 255)

Comment: 41345 (among others) won't fit in a byte.

Comment: You cant do this - anything over 255 wont fit into a byte!

Comment: Do you mean read decimal numbers from a file?

Comment: Please clarify your question. As it stands right now, I doubt you will get any useful answer.

Comment: Though the question was not perfectly worded, personally, I thought it was pretty clear what the asker was after.  @sfxworks: If my changes do not accurately reflect your wishes, feel free to revert.

Comment: Well you have to read the numbers from a file (are you stuck on that bit?). Then you have to check if the number is already in the array (are you stuck on that bit?). Then you have to add the number to the array (are you stuck on that bit?). You see it helps if you post the code you have already tried. That way we get to see what the problem is that you have.

Comment: Do you need to retain any kind of order?

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int64_t> v;
copy(istream_iterator<int64_t>(cin), istream_iterator<int64_t>(), back_inserter(v)); 
set<int64_t> s;
vector<int64_t> ov; ov.reserve(v.size());
for( auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i ) {
  if ( s.insert(v[i]).second ) 
     ov.push_back(v[i]);
}
// ov contains only unique numbers in the same order as the original input file.
```